# How to make an array of a parent class, made out of different subclasses

Tags: c++, subclass

I have a class `Item`, and there are two classes derived from it `Sword` and `Shield`.

I want my `player` to have an array of items:

```
class Item
{
    int x;
};

class Sword : public Item
{
     int sharpness = 10;
};

class Shield : public Item
{
    int blockChance = 2;
};

class player 
{
    Item* items[4];
    player()
    {
        items[0] = new Sword;
        items[1] = new Sword;
        items[2] = new Shield;
        items[3] = new Shield;
    }
};
```

Is there a way I can access values of `Sword` or `Shield` from `items`, for example:

```
items[2]->blockChance;
```

without having a separate array of `Sword`s and `Shield`s

If this is not possible, then I would just have a separate array of each, but a single array containing both would make this much easier

Comment: *and use simple words in your answers.* -- I suggest removing this from your question.  The answer(s) you will get will be adequate for general C++ programmers to understand.

Comment: Add a virtual method in `Item` then just override them in derived classes?

Comment: The `Item` class is missing a virtual destructor.  If your code went ahead and tried to call `delete` on those seperate items, then the behavior of the program is undefined.

Comment: Suggestion: `std::array<Item*, 4> items` which may also be `std::array<std::unique_ptr<Item>, 4>` or `std::array<std::shared_ptr<Item>, 4>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access the properties of a derived class via the base class, you can add a [**virtual method**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual). This is a method a derived class can override to provide a different implementation. If the base class has no meaningful implementation for it, it can also be [**abstract** (AKA pure-virtual)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/abstract_class), which will force the derived class to implement it.

There are several other issues you should be aware of:

1. When dealing with inheritance and virtuals method, it is important to have a [**virtual destructor**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors) in the base class. Otherwise the destructor of the derived classed will not be invoked when they are access via a pointer/reference (even if in your toy example this is not relevant, it's a good practice).
2. Instead of using raw C arrays, you should favor [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) for static sized arrays, and [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for dynamic sized ones.
3. Instead of using raw pointers with manual `new`/`delete`, you should use [**smart pointers**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one): [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) (the default), or [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) (if shared ownership is required).
4. You can use a [**member initialization list**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) to init `items` in the constructor of class `Player`.

The complete solution is  demonstrated below:

```
#include <array>    // for std::array
#include <memory>   // for std::unique_ptr
#include <iostream> // for std::cout etc.

class Item
{
public:
    virtual ~Item() {}              // important to add a virtual destructor
    virtual int GetProperty() = 0;  // a virtual method for accessing the property
};

class Sword : public Item
{
    int sharpness = 10;
public:
    int GetProperty() override { return sharpness; }   // override of the virtual method
};

class Shield : public Item
{
    int blockChance = 2;
public:
    int GetProperty() override { return blockChance; } // override of the virtual method
};

class Player
{
    std::array<std::unique_ptr<Item>, 4> items; // use std::array instead of a raw C array (or std::vector for a dynamic array), 
                                                // and std::unique_ptr instead of a raw poniter.
public:
    Player() 
        : items{ std::make_unique<Sword>(), 
                 std::make_unique<Sword>(), 
                 std::make_unique<Shield>(), 
                 std::make_unique<Shield>() }   // use a member initialization list
          {}
    std::array<std::unique_ptr<Item>, 4>& GetItems() { return items; }
};

int main()
{
    Player player;
    std::cout << player.GetItems()[0]->GetProperty() << '\n';   // access the Sword property
    std::cout << player.GetItems()[2]->GetProperty() << '\n';   // access the Shield property
}
```

Output:

```
10
2
```

[Live demo - Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/vzPeanzdf)

Comment: Further, the initialization of the array in `player::player` can be done in a member initialization list.  `player() : items{ std::make_unique<Sword>(), std::make_unique<Sword>(), std::make_unique<Shield>(), std::make_unique<Shield>() } {}`

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way I can **access values of** Sword or Shield from items

Yes, you can add a virtual method that returns the value of the property as shown below.

Note also that you should use [smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one) to avoid manual memory management(`new`/`delete` etc).

```
class Item
{
    int x;
    public:
    //add this virtual method  
    virtual int GetProperty()
    {
        return x;
    }
    virtual ~Item(){}
};

class Sword : public Item
{
     int sharpness = 10;
     public:
     //override and return property value
     int GetProperty() override
     {
        return sharpness;  
     }
};

class Shield : public Item
{
    int blockChance = 2; 
    public:
    //override and return property value
    int GetProperty() override
    {
        return blockChance;   
    } 
};

class player 
{   
    Item* items[4];
    player()
    {
        items[0] = new Sword;
        items[1] = new Sword;
        items[2] = new Shield;
        items[3] = new Shield;

        items[0]->GetProperty(); //get value
        items[2]->GetProperty(); //get value 
    }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1eeTdf3EK)
[Demo using smart pointers](https://godbolt.org/z/rYPjWf9cq)

Answer (score 2):

When using inheritance an important thing to remember is the Liskov substitution principle, which says at the level of the parent class, every subclass must be indistinguishable from the parent - that is, no behaviour that contradicts the parent declaration. Normally you would cast down to the subclass (the subclass may have additional features, but not take away anything), but first you need to be able to identify in the parent class what subclass it really is. C++ has the `typeof` operator, which you can compare using `==`, then `dynamic_cast<>()` to get to the actual class (e.g. assign to a pointer).

Another thing which can avoid casting is to use virtual methods, with an ability to check if it's implemented, e.g `has_sharpness()` with `get_sharpness()`, if `has_sharpness()` is true you know `Item` is a sword (or maybe axe) and you can use the value retuned by `get_sharpness()`. In this case all classes implement the same interface so no casting is needed, even though only some properties apply.